Setting voice controlled temperature levels using Google YAML scripts with temperature sensors
I am trying to use scripts to control temperature, but not found a way to change it if I want it to be warmer than normal (or colder). There are no documented way of passing a parameter to scripts apart from having all possible entries as individual voice commands.
If it had not been for two things, I would have given up a long time ago:

the fact that voice control indicates it "should" work.
the fact (?) that there are no other way of storing any sort of state / generic number that I know of in google home??

Any other ways of getting this done?  (apart from buying a nest thermostat)?
I have an Tuya IR sender and successfully found that I can set up an AC (that does not exist physically) and bot set and read back temperature setting using voice. So I can say:  "Set living room temperature to 25 deg C" and it will confirm. When I ask "What is the living room temperature setting" it will respond "Living room temperature is set to 25 degrees C".
However in scripts this work fine and reads back using voice control:
actions:
      - type: device.command.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint # Set the target temperature.
        # Target temperature setpoint.
        thermostatTemperatureSetpoint: 24.6 C
        devices: AC - Stue

but not using the same device for starter, condition like this:
 - starters: # same result from both starters and condition... "Device is not supporting".
      - type: device.state.TemperatureSetting
        device: AC - Stue
        state: thermostatTemperatureSetpoint
        greaterThan: 26C

IF this work, I could use any temperature sensor to control outlets for a "dumb" AC or heater.
I have tried most combinations of these settings that I can and not found a solution.
